# I'm having trouble with a multiline regex in C#, how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code to attempt to extract the content of li tags.

```
        string blah = @"<ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>oof</li>
        </ul>";

        string liRegexString = @"(?:.)*?<li>(.*?)<\/li>(?:.?)*";
        Regex liRegex = new Regex(liRegexString, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Match liMatches = liRegex.Match(blah);
        if (liMatches.Success)
        {
            foreach (var group in liMatches.Groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The Regex started much simpler and without the multiline option, but I've been tweaking it to try to make it work.

I want results `foo`, `bar` and `oof` but instead I get `<li>foo</li>` and `foo`.

On top of this I it seems to work fine in Regex101, https://regex101.com/r/jY6rnz/1

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should not be trying to parse html with regex.  html is not regular and regex (Regular Expressions) will not work well with html.  Use a standard html parse method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7931009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will start by saying that I think as mentioned in comments you should be parsing HTML with a proper HTML parser such as the HtmlAgilityPack. Moving on to actually answer your question though...

The problem is that you are getting a single match because `liRegex.Match(blah);` only returns a single match. What you want is `liRegex.Matches(blah)` which will return all matches.

So your use would be:

```
var liMatches = liRegex.Matches(blah);
foreach(Match match in liMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex produces multiple matches when matched with `blah`. The method `Match` only returns the first match, which is the `foo` one. You are printing all groups in that first match. That will get you 1. the whole match 2. group 1 of the match.

If you want to get `foo` and `bar`, then you should print group 1 of *each* match. To do this you should get all the matches using `Matches` first. Then iterate over the `MatchCollection` and print `Groups[1]`:

```
string blah = @"<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li>oof</li>
</ul>";
string liRegexString = @"(?:.)*?<li>(.*?)<\/li>(?:.?)*";
Regex liRegex = new Regex(liRegexString, RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection liMatches = liRegex.Matches(blah);
foreach (var match in liMatches.Cast<Match>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```